# Unable to install Skype

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, skype

I'm getting the following errors when installing Skype.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I don't know how to remove the broken packages.

Comment: You can check any held packages by "apt-mark showhold", but I'm not sure if this is the problem. If there is any packages mentioned in your error logs are held, you can "sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>" to unhold them.

Comment: not working sir, how to check held package in error log??

Answer (score 2):

Since the output of uname -a gives x86_64, it means that you have a 64 bit version.

I suggest that you first try to remove traces of your skype install. You can do this by entering `sudo apt-get purge skype` in your terminal. It might be possible that you have to run `sudo apt-get purge skype-bin` also.

Then check if you have any held packets:
Open the `/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log` log file in a text editor.
Locate any "broken" packages and remove them with sudo apt-get remove .

**Note: in newer versions, the log is located in /var/log/apt/term.log instead.**

To install Skype again, you should first run following command

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Add the correct repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Then update & install Skype:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

Comment: I had followed above steps but it is again throwing same error, Error is : The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: and uname - a returns : 4.2.0-27-generic #32~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 15:32:26 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @nmajethiya See updated answer

Comment: Since I am new to Ubuntu, can you please answer how can I see that package is broken or there is ant held packet ??? I found term.log file

Comment: @nmajethiya Did you open the file?

Comment: yup I have opened file

Comment: @nmajethiya And what do you see there? Maybe you can edit your question with the output

Comment: Do I place whole content of file here ??

Comment: log file is too long to edit here??? what should I do?? Any suggestions ???

Comment: edited only doubtful things to question. please help